# How to load pdf file in iframe insted of downloading it?

Tags: jquery, pdf, iframe

Here is my problem.I am loading iframe in jquery ui dialog and on clicking preview button dialog opens and loads pdf file there.But the real problem is its working in my local but it is not working in same pc's same browser(chrome/mozilla) after uploading it to server.But while checking it from other pc its working fine.

On localhost while loading iframe its loading as 
Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/pdf: 
i can see it on console.

But while requesting it on server from my pc's browser 
i can not see Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/pdf:
and browser is downloading file instead of loading it in iframe.